# Spring: Not receiving messages on email

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email, dependency-injection

I am not receiving on email accounts messages with activation registration.
While signing up, in the database I see activation code, and I am enabled to log in, but I want to send emails to accounts with activation.

I tried to change port and tried to change "smtps" on "smtp"
my properties:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=mymail@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=mypass
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.protocol= smtps
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true;
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true;
mail.debug= true
```

MailConfig:

```java
@Configuration
public class MailConfig {

    @Value("${spring.mail.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.mail.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${spring.mail.port}")
    private int port;
    @Value("${spring.mail.protocol}")
    private String protocol;
    @Value("${mail.debug}")
    private String debug;
    @Value("${spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth}")
    private String auth;
    @Value("${spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable}")
    private String enable;

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost(host);
        mailSender.setPort(port);
        mailSender.setUsername(username);
        mailSender.setPassword(password);

        Properties properties = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();

        properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", protocol);
        properties.setProperty("mail.debug", debug);
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", auth);
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", enable);

        return mailSender;
    }

}
```

UserService:

```java
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final MailSender mailSender;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, MailSender mailSender) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

    public boolean registerUser(User user) {
        User userFromDb = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

        if (userFromDb != null) {
            return false;
        }

        user.setActive(true);
        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(Role.USER));
        user.setActivationCode(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        userRepository.save(user);

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getEmail())) {
            String message = String.format("Hello, %s \n" + "Welcome to Sweater. Please visit link: http://localhost:8080/activate/%s",
                    user.getUsername(),
                    user.getActivationCode()
            );
            mailSender.send(user.getEmail(), "Activation code", message);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean activateCode(String code) {
        User user = userRepository.findByActivationCode(code);

        if (user == null) {
            return false;
        }

        user.setActivationCode(null);
        userRepository.save(user);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Controller

```java
@GetMapping("/activate/{code}")
    public String activate(Model model, @PathVariable String code) {

        boolean isActivated = userService.activateCode(code);

        if(isActivated){
            model.addAttribute("info", "User activated");
        }else {
            model.addAttribute("info", "Activation code is not found");
        }

        return "login";

    }
```

Comment: `@Autowired` the `MailSender`

Comment: @PatelRomil but why? i heared private final + constructors are better than Autowired. But When i changed everything to Autowired, it works)

Answer (score 0):

`@Autowired` the `MailSender`

*Dependency Injection:* The `@Autowired` annotation in spring *automatically injects the dependent beans* into the associated references of a POJO class. This annotation will inject the dependent beans by matching the data-type (i.e. Works internally as Autowiring byType). We can

- `@Autowired` on property
- `@Autowired` on the setter method
- `@Autowired` on the constructor (better over the individual field auto-wiring)

Comment: so i had to Autowrited constructor? Because I thought, if use constructor, then i dont need use annotation Autowired

Comment: You can autowire construction and a particular property, it's depends on us, but having constructor doesn't relate with dependency injection.